# Runtime error 1004 : paste method of worksheet class failed

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

There is lots of info on this error and how to fix but I've tried so many of them and nothing has worked: see below the problem chunk of code

```
Range("A1:K2").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("EIL Depannage Register.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Raising Depannage").Select
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Sheets("Import_Sheet").Select
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Range("A1").Select
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
ActiveSheet.Paste    <<<<<error happens at this line
```

Error occurring on the last line with .Paste.

Comment: You are likely getting tripped up because you're heavily using `Select` and `Activate` when you don't need to. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/3554/always-use-option-explicit#t=201703221343556120854), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/11274/always-define-and-set-references-to-all-workbooks-and-sheets#t=201703221343556120854), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate#t=201703221343556120854).

Comment: Thanks for the tips - new to all this so appreciate the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.Unprotect` commands are cancelling your `.CutCopyMode` so there is essentially nothing to paste. You will have to unprotect the worksheets **before** initiating a Copy and Paste operation.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Windows("EIL Depannage Register.xlsm").Activate
With ActiveWorkbook
    .Worksheets("Raising Depannage").Unprotect
    With .Worksheets("Import_Sheet")
        .Unprotect
        ws.Range("A1:K2").Copy Destination:=.Range("A1")
    End With
End With
```

I don't like using `ActiveSheet` to qualify the original worksheet but your code did not specify the workbook or worksheet and that left me little choice.

Comment: Thanks so much this work perfectly - sorry about the poor practices but i am new to vba and constantly learning... Thanks again :)

Comment: No worries, it is common practice for novices as that is the way that recorded code shows up. Many of the answers here will try and steer you away from the Select and Activate methods. The recommended reading from [PeterT's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42953199/runtime-error-1004-paste-method-of-worksheet-class-failed#comment73001622_42953199) above is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it like this?

```
Range("A1:K2").Copy
Windows("EIL Depannage Register.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Raising Depannage").Unprotect
Sheets("Import_Sheet").Unprotect
Sheets("Import_Sheet").Range("A1").Paste
```

Edit:
How about like this:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

set wb = activeworkbook
set ws = activesheet

Windows("EIL Depannage Register.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Raising Depannage").Unprotect
Sheets("Import_Sheet").Unprotect

wb.ws.Range("A1:K2").Copy
Windows("EIL Depannage Register.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Import_Sheet").Range("A1").Paste
```

Play a bit, it should work.

Comment: Breaks down on last line - "object doesn't support property or method"

Comment: You need to use `PasteSpecial`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
dim shSrc as worksheet
dim shTarget as worksheet
set shSrc =Workbooks("EIL Depannage Register.xlsm").Sheets("Raising Depannage")
set shTarget =Workbooks("EIL Depannage Register.xlsm").Sheets("Raising Depannage")
shSrc.unprotect
shTarget.unprotect
shSrc.Range("A1:K2").Copy
shTarget. Range("A1").Paste   
shSrc.protect
shTarget.protect
set shsrc=nothing
set shtarget=nothing`
```

just fix the source and target and verify the ranges

Answer (score 0):

The last line of the code should be:

```
Sheets("Import_Sheet").paste Range("A1")
```

as paste is a method of worksheet, and `range("A1")` is the destination argument.